# Jenkins "Invalid Username and Password" PAM Authentication

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, pam

I am running Jenkins `2.164` in RHEL with Centrify as AD connector.  I have configured Jenkins security to use PAM.  The PAM security configuration test is `Success` and Matrix Security is also able to validate users and group via `PAM`.  When restarting Jenkins and login, it doesn't seem to be able to authenticate via PAM and keeps getting "invalid username or password error".  I am using `Pam-Auth` plugin version `1.5`.  The weird part is when I am using an older version of Jenkins `2.89`, it works.  Also, the new Jenkins has changed the login form to a SimpleLogin and I suspect that causes incompatibility with my Centrify.

I have checked the `/var/log/messages` file and I keep receiving the following error.  This has never happened before in the older version.  I am not sure why the older version of Jenkins works but not the current version I'm using.

I've tried to swap to an older version of libpam4j-1.8 before `pam_setcred` was being introduced in `1.11` version, but still fail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Apr 24 23:45:26 adclient[35963]: INFO  AUDIT_TRAIL|Centrify Suite|PAM|1.0|201|PAM set credentials 
denied|5|user=test(type:ad,test@testdomain.com) pid=180 utc=1556163926715 centrifyEventID=24201 status=DENIED service=sshd tty=(none) client=(none) reason=Failed to set user credentials
```

Comment: I have tried latest version Jenkins `2.174` but still getting the same PAM set credential denied error.  Similar issue happen in MapR and they said is something to do with `libpam4j`.  I really doubt because it works for older version of Jenkins.  https://mapr.com/support/s/article/User-is-unable-to-login-on-the-MCS-page-after-upgrading-the-secure-cluster-to-6-0-version?language=en_US

Comment: Found out that the issue was due to Jenkins process was running as `jenkins` user.  `CentrifyDC` doesn't seems to allow non-root user to set PAM credential.  Even I have added `jenkins` user to `root` group, it still fail.  Finally I have run the Jenkins process as `root` user and the PAM works.